# Using grep command and backreferencing

Tags: grep, regular-expression

This is a pretty basic question, but I can't get my head around it.  I'm learning Linux and one of the questions i've been given is;

> *The word sentimentalment includes the same three characters (e.g. "ent") which appear three times. The word "blayblapblam" also contains
>   the same three characters repeated three time (e.g. "bla").
>
> How many words can you find which contain any three characters
>   repeated three times, like the examples "sentimentalment" and
>   "blayblapblam", but which also begin with lower case "d". Use
>   /usr/share/dict/words as your list of possible words and grep to find
>   the answer. The "d" is not one of the characters considered when
>   detecting the three-character strings.*

So far, I can return instances where the same three letters appear twice;

```
grep -E '^d(...).*\1' /usr/share/dict/words > output
```

Which to me reads, look for a word beginning with 'd', then combination of three letters, 0 or more characters before the same group (1) appearing again.

I've tried the following;

```
grep -E '^d(...).*\1.*\1' /usr/share/dict/words > output
```

Which if my understanding is correct (which it obviously isn't), returns group one, then zero or more characters, then group one again.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, neither "sentimentalment" nor "blayblapblam" are words or even common proper nouns in the English language, which is what I assume `/usr/share/dict/words` contains.  I was unable to find any words that match the pattern described above in my local words file.

Comment: The POSIX standard removed the support of back-references for extended regular expressions, so you can't rely on all `grep` versions supporting it. To be safe, use basic regular expressions, which even makes the command shorter in this case: `grep '^d.*\(...\).*\1.*\1'`

Answer (score 9):

It seems you fixed the three letters to go right after the `d`. Perhaps you would need something like this instead:

`grep -E '^d.*(...).*\1' /usr/share/dict/words > output`

which would make your 3-pattern search into

`grep -E '^d.*(...).*\1.*\1' /usr/share/dict/words > output`

For portability reasons one should avoid combining extended regular expressions with back-references, so better use

`grep '^d.*\(...\).*\1.*\1' /usr/share/dict/words > output`

Comment: I believe this answer is exactly what you need. Bear in mind that on my system it returns no results from /usr/share/dict/words. It is, nevertheless, correct.

Comment: @terdon I don't have `/usr/share/dict/words` but tried it on some sample input, and it seems to have behaved as expected.

Comment: yes it does, absolutely, that's why I upvoted it :). I am just warning the OP that if there is no output, it does not mean that your solution is wrong.

Comment: @terdon Thank you... wonder why it takes forever to get such one-liners accepted...

Comment: @terdon Btw, shouldn't both regexps have an extra `.*` at the end? Like: `'^d.*(...).*\1.*'` and `'^d.*(...).*\1.*\1.*'`

Comment: @Utku no, `grep` will print any line as long as part of the line matches the pattern given. You don't need to match the entire line.

Comment: The German `/usr/share/dict/words` finds `dereferenzieren`, a word clearly used once in a decade. (-;